# StrongSwan/IPSec: Manually trigger a rekey

Tags: linux-networking, ipsec, strongswan

I'm trying to test the performance of my StrongSwan RoadWarrior setup ([The standard one found here](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/swanctl/rw-cert/)). As part of this testing, I need to make sure it re-keys properly. I'm not all that familiar with IPSec, but is there a way to manually trigger a rekeying instead of letting it expire in the lifetime? Currently my `swanctl.conf` has a rekey time set that I *could* shorten, but I'd like to be able to do it at will with a oneliner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rekeyings can be triggered manually via [`swanctl`](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/swanctl)/[VICI](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Vici) but also with the legacy `ipsec` script (that's not documented, though).

For swanctl, the command is `--rekey`. The IKE or Child SA to rekey can be selected either by name (`--ike/--child`) or by unique ID (`--ike-id/--child-id`), which can be determined via `--list-sas` command. All SAs that match the given selectors are rekeyed and for IKE SAs it's also possible to trigger a reauthentication via `--reauth` option. VICI provides the same options via `rekey()` command, which `swanctl` uses.

With the `ipsec` script, the undocumented `rekey` command of the `stroke` utility may be used, i.e. `ipsec stroke rekey <name>`. The format of `<name>` determines what SA is rekeyed, similar to the [`down` command](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ipseccommand). For instance, use `name` or `name[]` to rekey the first IKE SA with that name, or `name{}` for the first Child SA, putting numbers in `[]` or `{}` allows rekeying via unique ID (the name is optional then), with `name[*]` or `name{*}` all SAs with the given name are rekeyed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Turns out it was also on the manpages, whoops :P One problem, though, I used the `swanctl --rekey` command, but I got an error: `rekey failed: missing rekey selector` I can't seem to find any information beyond inserting some arcane field in my `ipsec.conf`. Any advice for that?

Comment: You need to specify which SA to rekey, either by name and/or ID, using the parameters I described.